# Using angularjs with asp.net webforms

Tags: angularjs, webforms

I'd like to know if someone had any experience using  angularjs in asp.net webforms project. I understand that it is probably an overkill considering webforms ecosystem, but still... have you ever tried it ? Is it the worst idea ever ? If possible, would you use angularjs in new (webforms) project, and would you introduce it in an existing, medium size, project ?

Comment: I wish if this question was not closed. We still live in a world with lot many legacy web applications. For them, we may not be able to rewrite the entire site in one day. Neither we can live without it. But for new requirements and functionality, we may certainly want to use the most updated technologies like angular. I wish if I knew the answer of this question and giving him a +1 for asking such a good question.